# JNI - Class loading problem. DefineClass function doesn't seems to work

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to load specific classes using JNI. The problem is that `DefineClass()` function doesn't seems to work. And when I try to run function `FindClass()` it throws `ClassNotFoundError`. The class that I'm trying to load is a simple Main class with main method and "hello from world" in it. And it's package is correct.

This is what I've managed to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <jni.h>

int main() {

    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;

    JavaVMInitArgs arguments;
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=";

    arguments.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    arguments.nOptions = 1;
    arguments.options = options;
    arguments.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    jint response = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &arguments);
    delete[] options;

    if (response != JNI_OK) {
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "JVM load succeeded. Version ";
    jint ver = env->GetVersion();
    std::cout << ((ver >> 16) & 0x0f) << "." << (ver & 0x0f) << std::endl;

    std::ifstream fl("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Main.class");
    fl.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t lenght = fl.tellg();
    char* buffer = new char[lenght];
    fl.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    fl.read(buffer, lenght);
    fl.close();

    jclass mainClazz = env->DefineClass("Main", NULL, (const jbyte*) buffer, lenght);

    delete[] buffer;
    
    if (mainClazz == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: class not found!";
        jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
        return 0;
    }

    jmethodID mainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(mainClazz, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    jobjectArray args = env->NewObjectArray(0, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), 0);

    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(mainClazz, mainMethod, args);

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is working on Java 14, on Debian. Maybe your Path to Main.class is wrong.

Comment: Try changing: C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Main.class to C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Main.class (Replace / by \\) Maybe this is somehow a problem, although I'm not sure whether windows can handle / and \ as separators

Comment: 1) `std::ifstream fl("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Main.class");` -- You didn't check if this was successful.  -- 2)  `char* buffer = new char[lenght];` -- for safe JNI purposes, you should always use RAII and containers and stay as far away as you can from `new[]` and `delete[]`.  You should use `std::vector<char>` here, because if one of the interim JNI functions fail, you have a memory leak due to never getting to the `delete[]` call.

Comment: @JCWasmx86 Nothing changed replacing file separator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, but this are only conventions... The code should work anyway...

Comment: @Acco Checking if a file was opened successfully is not "convention".  You can't just assume the file was opened successfully.

Comment: @Acco The code 'should work anyway' *if and only if* the file was opened successfully. The overwhelming presumption here is that it wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `DefineClass` fails you should see if there are any pending exceptions.
The exception will probably be that your class file is malformed somehow, because you are opening your `ifstream` in text mode, where it happily replaces 0x0A bytes with a 0x0D 0x0A pair.

Use binary mode instead:

```
std::ifstream fl("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Main.class", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
```